# Хотел сделать динамическое имя для файла после отправки формы на django

Tags: django, форма

Вот у меня есть код в vievs.py, Form.py и модель в базе с направлением файлов в 1 папку, и все формы которые были загружаны они все сохраняются в единую папку, а мне нужно разбить их по определенному отправленному поле, например:
Ввели в поле: 'file_title_1',
И прекрепили файл: 'file_1.jpg'
а в базе она сохранилась так: 'file_title_1/file_1.jpg'

А потом другой файл:
Ввели в поле: 'file_title_2',
И прекрепили файл: 'file_2.jpg'
а в базе она сохранилась так: 'file_title_2/file_2.jpg'

Примерно так, основной мысль я думаю понятно) Я уже пытался с views обработки взять данные с этого поле и вставить как имя папки но не получается